# Python tkinter passing object between callbacks

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I'm trying to update a label based on a button press that does some calculations first, but I'm getting an error I don't understand.

Background: This method was working fine in previous iterations. I have not changed the code. But I did make some changes to the class by adding a controller to the initial instantiation of the `ShelfDownloader` class, which these methods belong to. To clarify `ShelfDownloader` is only called once from a different module.

Description: On the initial call of this class, it displays the `self.total_books_label` correctly, but when I switch shelves it chokes. **UPDATE:** It seems I am passing a string, but I in the comments I posted what I tried and I still don't understand the error. See the second error:

Question: Since that's probably not the problem, I'm thinking one of my calls is missing something. Any suggestions please?

*I removed the widget formatting for this question. I included these bits of code to help with the Error message.*

```
class ShelfDownloader(ctk.CTkFrame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        ctk.CTkFrame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.parent = parent
        self.controller = controller
        ...

    def shelf_option_callback(self, parent, *args):
        if not self.downloader:
            sys.exit()
        shelf_choice = [s for s in SHELF_METADATA if self.shelf_choice_var.get() in s['shelf_name']][0]
        for k, v in shelf_choice.items():
            self.downloader_dict[k] = v
        updated_dict = self.downloader.update_shelf(**self.downloader_dict)
        for k, v in updated_dict.items():
            self.downloader_dict[k] = v
        self.display_total_books_and_pages(parent)

    def draw_top_panel(self):
        parent = self.top_frame
        LL1 = ctk.CTkLabel(parent, text="Choose shelf to download:")
        # LL1.pack()
        shelf_opt_menu = ctk.CTkOptionMenu(master=parent, width=170, variable=self.shelf_choice_var, 
values=self.shelf_list,
command= lambda: self.shelf_option_callback(parent)  
##      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ 
## This is my problem spot. Tried adding 
## command=self.shelf_option_callback(parent)
## but different error.

        shelf_opt_menu.pack()

    def display_total_books_and_pages(self, parent):
        if hasattr(self, 'total_books_label'):
            self.total_books_label.destroy()
        ## GUI feedback info, partially a debugging tool
        _books, _pages = (self.downloader_dict['total_book_count'], self.downloader_dict['total_page_count'])
        self.display_text.set(f"Shelf has {_books} books, retrieving {_pages} pages.")
        logger.debug(f"{self.display_text.get()}")
        logger.debug(f"display_total_books_and_pages: {type(self.display_text)}") 
        self.total_books_label = ctk.CTkLabel(master=parent, width=180, 
                                              text=f"{self.display_text.get()}")
        self.total_books_label.pack()
```

My debugging returns correct and expected output after I switch the shelf, ie `shelf_opt_menu`:

```
2022-12-12 12:05:22,612, gui_download, 183:  Shelf has 1624 books, retrieving 17 pages.
2022-12-12 12:05:22,612, gui_download, 184:  display_total_books_and_pages: <class 'tkinter.StringVar'>
```

I get an error message that I'm passing a string in the code above. UPDATE: I trimmed the full error out since I confirmed that's what is happening with `logger.debug(f"{type(parent)}")`

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\megha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1948, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
...
  File "c:\MyProjects\gr_shelf_tools\src\gui_downloader.py", line 124, in shelf_option_callback
    self.display_total_books_and_pages(parent)
  File "c:\MyProjects\gr_shelf_tools\src\gui_downloader.py", line 184, in display_total_books_and_pages
    self.total_books_label = ctk.CTkLabel(master=parent, width=180, text=f"{self.display_text.get()}")
                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
...
  File "C:\Users\megha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2591, in _setup
    self.tk = master.tk
              ^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'tk'
```

Error 2 (when I change it to a lambda call):

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\megha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1948, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\megha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\customtkinter\windows\widgets\core_widget_classes\dropdown_menu.py", line 101, in <lambda>
    command=lambda v=value: self._button_callback(v),
                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\megha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\customtkinter\windows\widgets\core_widget_classes\dropdown_menu.py", line 106, in _button_callback
    self._command(value)
  File "C:\Users\megha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\customtkinter\windows\widgets\ctk_optionmenu.py", line 381, in _dropdown_callback
    self._command(self._current_value)
TypeError: ShelfDownloader.draw_top_panel.<locals>.<lambda>() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given
```

Comment: Have you tried printing `parent` that's being passed into `shelf_option_callback` to see what it is? It looks to me like it's a string and not a `Tk` instance.

Comment: First, thank you for response! OK, yes, it's a string. So I tred changing it to `command=lambda: self.shelf_option_callback(parent)`. I get this error: `TypeError: ShelfDownloader.draw_top_panel.<locals>.<lambda>() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given`. That's with or without `parent` in the `def shelf_option_callback(self, ..., *args):`

Comment: Something like `command=lambda *args: self.shelf_option_callback(parent, *args)` should work.

Comment: I tried that second one (copy/paste) and don't think I understand the call arguments well enough because I go this error: `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'shelf_option_callback'`. Will have to study this tonight. Thank you!

Comment: The first one _should_ work. I wasn't able to test it, but the thought for the second was to bind `self` although on second thought, it didn't make much sense in that context.

Comment: This isn't really an answer but I fixed it with a workaround: I assigned `parent=self.top_frame` in the `def display_total_books_and_pages(self)` method instead of trying to pass it, since it was always the same Label widget being updated. Thank you for your response. I might see if I get anywhere with your suggestion later.

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't utilizing the StringVar, `self.display_text`, properly. I fixed it. Here's how: I set a trace in the callback `shelf_option_callback`. I call `self.set_display_text` from the `trace` to change the value of `self.display_text`. I moved the Label creation to `draw_top_frame(self)` so that it always resides in the desired position and added the option `textvariable=self.display_text` to the Label. This did the trick.

The Label rewrites new values in the same spot when the `shelf_opt_menu` OptionMenu changes.

```
    def shelf_option_callback(self, *args):
        parent = self.top_frame
        if not self.downloader:
            sys.exit()
        shelf_choice = self.get_shelf_metadata() # a dictionary of values
        self.update_dictionary(**shelf_choice) # calculates new page counts based on the shelf
        self.display_text.trace('w', self.set_display_text())
        
    def draw_top_panel(self):
        ## Dropbox: shelf menu
        parent = self.top_frame
        self.initialize_downloader() # sets up a dictionary of defaults
        LL1 = ctk.CTkLabel(parent, text="Choose shelf to download:")
        LL1.pack(anchor=tk.NW, ipadx=10, padx=(20, 10))
        shelf_opt_menu = ctk.CTkOptionMenu(master=parent, width=170,
                                           variable=self.shelf_choice_var, 
                                           values=self.shelf_list,                                         
                                         command=self.shelf_option_callback)
        shelf_opt_menu.pack()

        ## Next option menu: download increment choices
        ## code here ...

        self.set_display_text()
        self.total_books_label = ctk.CTkLabel(master=self.top_frame, width=180, 
                                              textvariable= self.display_text, 
                                              text=f"{self.display_text.get()}")
        self.total_books_label.pack()
        ## A couple of RadioButtons
        ## code here
        

    def set_display_text(self, *args):
        _books, _pages = (self.downloader_dict['total_book_count'], self.downloader_dict['total_page_count'])
        self.display_text.set(f"Shelf has {_books} books, retrieving {_pages} pages.")
```

To simplify, although in this example the choices aren't really linked to anything.

```
def reset_text_var(*args):
    new_text = "String from somewhere"
    text_var.set(new_text)
    
def callback(*args):
    print("made it?")
    text_var.trace('w', reset_text_var())
    
root = tk.Tk()
text_var = tk.StringVar()
parent = tk.Frame(root)
parent.pack()
choices = ['Choice 1', 'Choice 2', 'Choice 3']
text_var.set("You haven't picked anything yet")
opt_menu = tk.OptionMenu(parent, text_var, *choices, command=callback)
a_label = tk.Label(parent, textvariable=text_var, text=f"Your new string: {text_var.get()}")
opt_menu.pack()
a_label.pack()
root.mainloop()
```